# Using different Fonts in PHP

Tags: php, fonts

How would I use different fonts in php

im doing something like this :

```
<?php 
if(isset($variable)) 
{
   echo 'A Boring Font';
} else {

 };
 ?>
```

how would i make the echo statement a different font?
thanks for any help!

Comment: PHP doesn't have fonts. Try searching for "font CSS".

Comment: I think you need to look at some basic **HTML** tutorials before trying this with PHP.

Comment: well i know how to do it with CSS but its a bit more complicated than that

Comment: @ChristianBartram No, it's not more complicated :) PHP *generates* output which is [usually] HTML+CSS. If you know CSS, then it ought to be trivial to generate the appropriate [HTML+CSS] output. (I recommend using external style-sheets, though.)

Comment: You nest your PHP in HTML. Try adding text outside of your PHP tags and styling it normally.

Comment: <p class="data_text"><?php 
    $status_query = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM Dashboard WHERE `session_id` = '$sessionID'");
    $status_result = mysql_result($status_query, 0); 
    if($status_result != '') {
     echo 'Status: ';
     echo $status_result;
    } else {
    } 
 ?></p> this doesnt work here.....   my css is like .data_text { font-family:"Myriad-Pro"; Font-size:15px; } etc....

Comment: Well, that code *might* have been useful to include the question (you can always edit the question!), including an explanation of what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @ChristianBartram as Paul said, please don't post code in the comments. (seriously, can *you* read that?!). [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17461777/edit) your original question to include any relevant code (or better yet, include it from the beginning!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $text = "It's really not that hard.";
   if(isset($fontname)) {
       echo "<span style=\"font-family: $fontname;\">";
       echo $text;
       echo "</span>";
   }
   else {
       echo "In a boring font, I say: " . $text;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in-built font then please use CSS.
If you want to use new font which is not in library, then you can use google font api or you can use some online webfont generator.

- This is one of free [webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)
- This is [Google Font API](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aPT+Sans)

Answer (score -1):

Example using jquery css and html, but as mentioned in comments php doesn't have fonts

html

```
<a href="#" class="font1">Boring Font</a>
<a href="#" class="font2">Awesome font</a>
<div>You chose <span class="fonttype">No Font</span></div>
```

css

.font1 {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
.font2 { 
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
}

jquery

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('font1') {
    $('.fonttype').text('boring font');
  } else {
    $('.fonttype').text('not boring font');
  }
  //or
  alert($(e.currentTarget).css('font-family');
});
```

Comment: ok thank you i will try both of these options out! its not insanely important its just been bothering me because i thought it was something i could fix quickly but its turning into a little hassle

Comment: -1 @Seth The OP very clearly asked about doing this with PHP. Why the heck would someone show an example using a different language (a client-side one, yet to boot!)  Is this how everyone does it these days... just throw some JQuery at it? No wonder the web is so slow.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you want to show everyone how to do this in php?

Comment: Gladly, @SethMcClaine. Certainly better than adding a bunch of unnecessary client-side bloat.